# Blank Ul not containing li shows padding and margin in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have dynamically generated dropdown menu. On mouse hover It shows blank space if one tab do not have dropdown options.

Comment: It would be *way* easier for us to answer your question if you show us (relevant parts of) your source code. Isn't that obvious?

Answer (score 1):

first create a css rule for all uls like:

```
ul{
margin: 0; padding:0; display: block;
}
```

and then if the ul is empty then try to clear any space inside the ul tag bcoz sometime browser will show an empty line space when dere is a line break in the code without using br tag..
mainly IE..